# what could prevents MPC-HC from opening and playing mov file?

Tags: video, prores

... and the strangest thing is that the very same file plays back just fine on a different (but very much identical) Win 10 system.

The file is a .mov prores video file. Both system have prores codec installed.

I reinstalled MPC-HC and reset all to default.

The file is playing in QuickTime Player (v7.7.9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProRes is only one of codecs using for encoding / decoding video into / from the `.mov` files container. You need other codecs, too, to be able play back all `.mov` files.

The Quick Time Player is the native player for the Apple's `.mov` files, so it has its own codecs for playing back them.

For Media Player Classic you need the appropriate codecs to be installed in your operating system (Windows 10).

Probably the simplest and most reliable method is to download and install the free [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) - the decision between its different versions (Basic, Standard, etc.) is up to you, all versions will cause that all media players will be able to play back all `.mov` files (and almost all others, too).

Comment: Downloading is installing the Standard version solved it. `prores hq, yuv422p10le` must somehow have been missing.